# How to quickly switch between "webcam preview" and XBMC?

Tags: webcam, autohotkey, kodi

I've build a dedicated PC for use in Dental Clinic, but I found out that it's very difficult to setup the computer "idiot-proof" enough.  It has to do 2 simple things:

1. **show live preview from intra-oral camera fullscreen**
   – no snapping pictures or recording videos needed, just show live output fullscreen
   – the camera has standard USB interface like any common webcam
2. **ability to play selected short instruction video on demand**
   – video player with non-desktop look&feel and simple UI = XBMC is great for this.

And there must be the ability to **switch between the two with simple keypress**.

I'd like to use no mouse at all. The connected mini-keyboard has very poor touchpad anyway...

**My temporal solution**
I already use a combination of Windows 7 + Cyberlink YouCam + XBMC + AutoHotkey, but this setup has a few major flaws:

1. something goes wrong every moment, it's not a "press this for camera, and press this for video section"
2. YouCam quits fullscreen mode every time it pops up some kind of message (connection lost) and after waking from sleep. I have to use touchpad to click OK and then click Fullsceen button again.
3. Win 7 is overkill for my needs, if I used for example OpenELEC, I wouldn't even need any hard drive. Second, I don't need OS with a desktop here.

**Is there any reliable solution?** OpenELEC or XBMCbuntu could be nice, but how to setup the system to perform this way?